# Is radius constant in rotation motion?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I wanted to calculate centripetal acceleration $a_c=r\omega^2$,however since centripetal acceleration is pulling the object then shouldn't radius also decrease and increase depending on the position of the object that is rotating in circular motion? [image]

The red line looks like it is closer to the center of the circle than the yellow line so if we have the rotating object at the tip of the red line we also have less radius?

Comment: Can you please clarify? If an object is in circular motion then by definition the radius cannot be changing.

Comment: Your right But the object is getting pulled toward the center of rotation meaning radius will decrease?

Comment: So then you do not mean to say circular motion

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: What do you mean that the red line looks closer to the center? In circular motion the red and yellow lines should be equally long.

Comment: It is still confusing, since the radius cannot change if you are requiring circular motion

Comment: Changed the answer to prevent the spread of misinformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular motion is, by definition, restricted to a circle. So:

$$\mathbf{r}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} r \cos \phi(t) \\ r \sin \phi(t) \end{pmatrix} $$

Note that the scalar $r$ is a constant, and $\phi(t)$ may be a non-linear function of time.

The time derivative is the velocity:

$$\mathbf{v}(t) = \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}(t)}{\partial t} = \begin{pmatrix} -\phi'(t) \,r\sin \phi(t) \\ \phi'(t) \,r\cos \phi(t)\end{pmatrix} $$

And the second time derivate is the acceleration:

$$\mathbf{a}(t) = \dfrac{\partial^2\mathbf{r}(t)}{\partial t^2} = \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{v}(t)}{\partial t} = \begin{pmatrix} -\phi''(t) \,r\sin \phi(t) -\phi'(t)^2 \,r\cos(\phi(t)) \\ \phi''(t) \,r\cos \phi(t) -\phi'(t)^2 \,r\sin(\phi(t)) \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{\phi''(t)}{\phi'(t)}\mathbf{v}(t) - \phi'(t)^2 \mathbf{r}(t)$$

In the case of constant $\phi'(t)=\omega$, the first term disappears and the acceleration is then purely centripetal.

Answer (score 2):

When there is *no* acceleration an object will move in a straight line. You *need* centripetal acceleration before something moves in a circle. Without centripetal acceleration you can't even define a radius. It is then natural to ask the question: say I want to move in a circle of radius $r$, how much acceleration do I need to do this? Let's define a particle that's moving along a circle with radius $r$ with angular velocity $\omega$. When $\omega$ is constant this is called uniform circular motion.
$$\vec r(t)=\pmatrix{r\cos(\omega t)\\
r\sin(\omega t)}$$
Now calculate the velocity by differentiating twice, considering that $r$ is constant:
$$\vec v(t)=\frac {d\vec r(t)}{dt}=\pmatrix{-r\omega\sin(\omega t)\\
r\omega\cos(\omega t)}$$
$$\vec a(t)=\frac {d\vec v(t)}{dt}=\pmatrix{-r\omega^2\cos(\omega t)\\
-r\omega^2\sin(\omega t)}=-\omega^2\vec r(t)$$
The length of this acceleration vector is $a_c=|-\omega^2 r(t)|=\omega^2r$.
So in conclusion, to move in a circle with radius $r$ and uniform angular velocity you need to accelerate with $a_c=\omega^2r$ in the direction of the center of the circle. **Any other acceleration will means there is no longer uniform circular motion.** When $\omega$ changes over time the acceleration can be different but uniform circular acceleration should enough to answer your question. If you're not familiar with vector notation don't be afraid to ask.